# Latex to Moodle -Quiz

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to write Quizzes using Moodle, but when I add .png picture to my document, when I upload it to Moodle, it doesn't show so what would be the problem.. If I could resolve this problem it will save me a lot of time.

I run it using PDFLatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother 
\usepackage{moodle}
\usepackage{tikz}
     \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external} % set this 
\tikzexternalize          % explicitly
\usepackage{steinmetz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{essay}[points=5]{Circuit01} 
If $\mathbf{H}(s)=\dfrac{V_L(s)}{V_s(s)}$, Find $\mathbf{H}(s)$ and $h(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\big[\mathbf{H}(s)\big]$
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{ENEC250216.png}
\end{center}
\end{essay}

\end{quiz}


\end{document}
```

I'm using Mac and my editor is TexShop

Comment: Your question is about Moodle, not about LaTeX. Moodle supports TeX-like notation, but to my knowledge, the TeX engine is not involved. So it might be better to ask in a Moodle forum. But even if someone on this site is familiar with Moodle (I'm a bit), it will be hardly possible to answer your question without any details. There are many plugins that can be used for writing questions and quizzes, and from your description it is not clear (to me), what you are trying to do, and how.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about TeX and friends

Comment: I suppose the OP is talking about the `moodle.sty` latex package, so it will be on topic. (@egreg)

Comment: Please, add an example... The typical problem is having a too old version of moodle.sty (use at least 0.8), or not having the tools installed, or forgetting `-shell-escape` (@gernot)

Comment: @Diana, would you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ? And explain *how* you compile the input file. `moodle.sty` works perfectly for me, with images and all.

Comment: I did, how would I know the version of moodle.sty

Comment: I get this msg, entering extended mode restricted \write8 enabled, doesn't that mean -shell-escape is enabled as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with figures in `moodle.sty`, check the following things:

1. you are running `pdflatex` (but better `xelatex` or `lualatex`, mandatory if you have non-ASCII characters) with the `-shell-escape` flag;
2. you have all the programs required for the conversion installed (see manual, use `texdoc moodle`, section 5.4, "external tools"); check that you do not have [permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453);
3. Use a recent version of `moodle.sty`, better if newer than 0.8 (the newly appointed maintainer is doing a great job in enhancing it).

It works here flawlessly for generating my Moodle quizzes, including figures, `tikzpicture`s and so on. You need to read the manual, though; only a subset of LaTeX macros can be safely translated to XML by the package, so you have to be aware of that.

Comment: So my problem is that I'm using pdflatex, unfortunately -shell-escape is not working, I'm using texmaker

Comment: @Diana So please add an MWE to the question, say which version of moodle.sty you are using, and show the log --- you should have a failure during the conversion. `texmaker` is just an editor, not your LaTeX distribution (that could be MikTeX, TeXLive, etc...). We do not even know which OS you are using. Your question is very near to be closed (for lack of focus and information), please help us to help you.